# How to get text from the title attribute when <th> is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following HTML:

```
<th title="Title Description">Blah</th>
```

How do I select text from the `title` attribute when I click on `<th>`?

Comment: where is the TR located? could you post more markup?

Comment: do you mean TH cuz your markup says TH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('th').click(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $('th').click(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        // do something useful with title
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('th').click(function() {
           var title = $(this).attr('title');
           alert(title);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('th').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('title'));});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    var title = $(this).children('th').attr('title');
});
```